# error 500 with jquery ajax get and flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

here is the flask python: http://pastie.org/8712899

and here is the html+js in the index.html template: http://pastie.org/8712901

The problem is that it works exactly as wanted when run via flask inbuilt server locally, but gives 500 error on clicking the search button when deployed with apache wsgi.

it is online here(but not functional)
http://thekindlyone.scribblehead.info/calvinball/

Help?

here is the log of traceback.

```
Exception on /search [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/webdev/thekindlyone/calvinball/calvinball.py", line 42, in find
    dbase=database('index')
  File "/home/webdev/thekindlyone/calvinball/calvinball.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.ix=open_dir(index_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/whoosh/index.py", line 123, in open_dir
    return FileIndex(storage, schema=schema, indexname=indexname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/whoosh/index.py", line 421, in __init__
    TOC.read(self.storage, self.indexname, schema=self._schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/whoosh/index.py", line 616, in read
    gen = cls._latest_generation(storage, indexname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/whoosh/index.py", line 593, in _latest_generation
    for filename in storage:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/whoosh/filedb/filestore.py", line 81, in __iter__
    return iter(self.list())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/whoosh/filedb/filestore.py", line 518, in list
    files = os.listdir(self.folder)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'index'
```

---

Update: I set the whoosh index directory path to absolute and also the cnh.cbz path to absolute. But I get [error](http://pastie.org/8714154) even after that. The whoosh index thing works though. Is it because the cnh.cbz file is outside the flask application directory? How do I fix this?
here is the new python

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from whoosh.index import open_dir
from whoosh.fields import *
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
from whoosh import highlight
import datetime
import zipfile
import logging
app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('/home/webdev/thekindlyone/flasklogs/calvinball.log'))
#yymmdd

class database(object):
    def __init__(self,index_dir):
        self.ix=open_dir(index_dir)
    def search(self,text):
        fetched=[]
        brf = highlight.UppercaseFormatter()
        with self.ix.searcher() as searcher:
            query = QueryParser("content", self.ix.schema).parse(text)
            results = searcher.search(query)
            results.fragmenter=highlight.WholeFragmenter()
            results.formatter = brf
            for result in results:
                fetched.append((result['title'],result.highlights("content")))
        return fetched

def makehtml(tuples):
    hypertext=''
    if tuples:
        for title,content in tuples:
            ftitle=datetime.datetime.strptime(title[2:], '%y%m%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y')
            hypertext+='''<div class="clicker" id="{0}">{1}</div><br>'''.format(title,ftitle+'   '+content)           
    else:
        hypertext='Nothing found'

    return hypertext

@app.route('/search')
def find():   
    string = request.args.get('searchstring')    
    dbase=database('/home/webdev/thekindlyone/calvinball/index')
    hypertext=makehtml(dbase.search(string))
    return hypertext


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/show')
def display():    
    strip = request.args.get('strip')
    z=zipfile.ZipFile('/home/webdev/thekindlyone/cnh.cbz')
    img=z.open(strip+'.jpg')
    z.close()
    data_uri = img.read().encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
    img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">'.format(data_uri)    
    return img_tag




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

---

Update 2: I created a hardlink for cnh.cbz to the flask application directory and it works. 
But there has to be a better way.

Comment: Configure stack traces to be sent to a logfile on your apache based server, that way you are not blind when you get a 500 error. If you can't still make sense of the error add the stack trace with your question.

Comment: @Miguel I can't. [This](http://pastie.org/8714023) is happening when I try to log.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error it seems you need to use an absolute pathname to your whoosh db, or at least set the current directory appropriately before you open it. It appears Apache does not set the current directory to your application's folder.

Comment: I set the absolute path for the whoosh db, and for the cnh.cbz zipfile. the whoosh stuff works with the absolute directory.. the zipfile doesn't. [traceback](http://pastie.org/8714154)